# Determine programmatically if the user's privacy settings were reset

Tags: ios, permissions, privacy, user-permissions

Is there a way to determine programmatically if the user's privacy settings were reset?
Via `Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy`

I am currently working on a framework to make it easier to ask for the user's permission and provide more context: [ISHPermissionKit](https://github.com/iosphere/ISHPermissionKit)

In some instances (e.g. when storing "Don't ask me again") it would be good if I could also reset the internal state of the permissions framework if the system resets.

One way would obviously be to check if a previously granted/denied status is now undetermined (e.g. location). This however requires to check a multitude of permissions and is not possible for all permission categories.

I have check both `[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier]` and `[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]` both remain unchanged when resetting the privacy.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this can't be done. There is no delegate call that does this. The best way is to check on

> applicationDidBecomeActive:

Comment: How would you check that if you do not store if the user previously made a choice?

Comment: You would have to store it. For example, when user allows push notifications you can do: UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
and store the types. Then in applicationDidBecomeActive: you can check if that has changed. You can do the same with addressbook as well as location.

Comment: I am aware of this technique/strategy, however the question specifically looks for ways that work without checking permissions or storing previous decisions.

Comment: This is aimed to be of general use and should not be limited to remoteNotifications or location permissions. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: I understand and I said there's no way that I know of as stated in my original answer. Worked at Apple for four years on the iOS team. In addition, you should be aware that there are many new permission in iOS8 such as "continued background location usage".

Comment: That's what I suspected. Filing a radar also seems pretty hopeless as this is probably by design.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry for the bad news although "-1" does seem harsh since I did answer your question (though not what you wanted.) Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, that might have been a bit premature, but before the comments the answer was lacking a bit of depth ;). You will need to edit your answer otherwise I can't undo the vote.

Comment: Done. Thanks and good luck. It seems like you are building something that will be really convenient.

Comment: Would appreciate it if would reset the score to 0 at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(privacyWasReset:)  
           name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
         object:nil];



[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];
to ->appDidBecomeActive method and also
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(privacyWasReset) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];
to-> applicationDidEnterBackground method.
```

This is might help you..

Comment: Is that called after the app relaunches if the settings have been reset while the app was not running? From the docs it sounds like it is only called when changing actual `NSUserDefaults` values.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AppPrefs/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: The comments in that project seem to imply that this only relates to settings and not the permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately this notification is not triggered when resetting the privacy.